# Wcf reference can not be updated

Tags: c#, odata, web-reference

When i try to update my wcf reference i am getting error like below:

[image]

In vs2017 if i try to add reference again then i am getting error like below:

[image]

Can some body help??

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this issue at this link:https://github.com/OData/lab/issues/64

The link mentions your specific problem.
First install Microsoft WCF Toolkit.

Then go to the registry, find the following key:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services]

and rename "VS 2010 Tooling" to "VS 2014 Tooling"